# Trying to get existing entity from datastore but return undefined (not found)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am just learning google datastore with node.js.

I can successfully put some entity into the server but for some reason I was not able to get back the newly created entity from my datastore.

```
namespace: default
kind: User
```

[image]

Here is the code to get entity from datastore:

```
module.exports.getUser = function( userId, callback){

    console.log( typeof userId);
    console.log('[DataStore] finding user...(ID=' + userId + ')');

    var userKey = dataStore.key(['User', userId]);

    dataStore.get( userKey, function(err, entity) {

        console.log(err);
       console.log(entity);

        if (err) { return callback(err); }
        callback(null, entity);
    });
};
```

I don't know why but it failed to get my entity.

I know undefined means entity not exist but it is actually there.

Result:

[image]

I think it may be caused by some simple mistake.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found that the *automatically assigned key* is an **integer**!

I was confused by the google samples thinking that the keys are always a string.